# Problema al imprimir un puntero que apunta a un cadena de caracteres

Tags: c

Me pueden decir cual es mi error, quiero leer una cadena de caracteres y luego imprimirlo uno por uno.

Ejemplo:

> ```
> leer 'ejemplo'
> imprimir 'e'
> imprimir 'j'
> imprimir 'e'
> imprimir 'm'
> imprimir 'p'
> imprimir 'l'
> imprimir 'o'**
> ```

```
void PasarArreglo(char Arreglo[]);
int main()
{
    char OtroArreglo[100];
    printf("ingrese la cadena de caracteres: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(OtroArreglo);
    PasarArreglo(OtroArreglo);

    return 0;
}

void PasarArreglo(char Arreglo[])
{
   int i;

   for(i=0;i>=100;++i)
   {
     printf("elemento[%i]: %c ",i+1,Arreglo[i]);
   }

}
```

Comment: Tu condición está mal, no es `for(i=0;i>=100;++i)`, es `for(i=0;i<100;++i)`. Ya que estas usando strings también te recomiendo cambiar ese for por `for(i=0;Arreglo[i];++i)`, así vas a evitar imprimir elementos fuera de la string.

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda..

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un par de problemas en el código. Uno obvio, el otro un poco más delicado.

Primero, tu bucle usa como condición `i>=100`, en vez de `i<=100`. Tu condición es falsa ya desde el principio, por lo que el bucle no se ejecuta y por eso no se imprime nada.

El problema más delicado es que si pones `i<=100`, entonces se ejecutará 100 veces, pero si el texto que ha introducido el usuario tiene menos de 100 caracteres, empezarás a ver "basura" a partir del punto donde se termina la entrada del usuario.

Por ejemplo, si el usuario ha puesto "Hola", la salida podría ser algo como:

```
elemento[1]: h
elemento[2]: o
elemento[3]: l
elemento[4]: a
elemento[5]: 
elemento[6]: �
...
elemento[99]: �
elemento[100]: �
```

Donde esos `�` representan bytes con valores aleatorios, que estaban ahí en la variable `OtroArreglo[]` y que no han sido sobreescritos por el texto introducido por el usuario.

Para evitar ese problema no debes iterar 100 veces, sino tantas como la longitud de la cadena, la cual puedes averiguar con `strlen(Arreglo)`.

La función `strlen()` puede contar cuántas letras hay en realidad porque la función `gets()` ha puesto un byte de valor 0 al final del texto introducido por el usuario. En este ejemplo, tras "hola", el siguiente byte valdría 0 (al imprimirlo no se ve porque es el ASCII Nulo)

Por tanto también podrías usar tú este hecho (que hay un cero marcando el final) y en lugar de usar un bucle for usar un `while`:

```
void PasarArreglo(char Arreglo[])
{
   int i=0;

   while(Arreglo[i] != 0)
   {
     printf("elemento[%i]: %c\n",i+1,Arreglo[i]);
     i++;
   }
}
```

Ejemplo de ejecución:

```
ingrese la cadena de caracteres: Hola
elemento[1]: H
elemento[2]: o
elemento[3]: l
elemento[4]: a
```